# Dynamic MDX imports with Next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Just followed the [Next13 + MDX Tutorial](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/guides/mdx), but I am still not sure how I can load my mdx files dynamically? I do not have my mdx files on some remote server, so I do not need `next-mdx-remote`. However, I do need a way to load a different mdx file depending on my route (e.g. `/blog/[slug]`). All my mdx files are in the same repo.

So when a user requests `/blog/article-1` I want to import my `article1.mdx` file. In the tutorial, this is just a hard-coded import for a static page:

```js
import HelloWorld from './hello.mdx';

export default function Page() {
  return <HelloWorld />;
}
```

...but I need the page & the imports to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you could run a function that will run on the server like
`const blogPages = await getBlogPages();`

and inside you could do this

```
const blogPath = "./src/app/blog/[slug]/";
const getBlogPages = async (): Promise<
  Array<{
    fileName: string;
    path: string;
  }>
> => {
  const blogPages = await glob("*.mdx", {
    cwd: blogPath,
  });
// and so on
```

Now, its still not quite the same as how you would do it in Next < 13, but it accomplishes what you want

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on same issue, this works but I am not sure this is the right way to go. This will be the page under dynamic route e.g [title]/page.jsx and will receive "title" as a prop.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
export default async function Post({params:{title}})
{
    const Content = await getPostData(title);
    return (<div>{<Content />}</div>)
}

async function getPostData(title)
{
    return dynamic(() => import(`../../content/${title}.mdx`));
}
```